# How to exclude a certain class in fetching contents from a webpage?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm using ***SIMPLE_HTML_DOM*** as my parser.

So here's the thing I've already get the contents using a certain div with class, but that div has a child div that are unnecessary that I don't want to get when I run the parser.

```
    $main_body = $html->find('div[class=storypage-divider desktop]', 0)->plaintext;
    echo $main_body;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the child element that you do not want and delete it.

```
 $main_body = $html->find('div[class=storypage-divider desktop]', 0);
 $main_body->find('div[class=do-not-want]', 0 )->outertext = '';
 echo  $main_body->plaintext;
```

*Note: I did not test this code!, and change the class name "do-not-want"*

Hope that helped.

Comment: Hi sir, I tried your code, it has error.
`Call to a member function first() on array`

Comment: Hi there, if it is an array i think you should try : 
`$main_body = $html->find('div[class=storypage-divider desktop]', 0);`
` $main_body->find('div[class=do-not-want]')[0]->outertext = '';`
`echo  $main_body->plaintext;`

Comment: Please try this:
`$main_body = $html->find('div[class=storypage-divider desktop]', 0);
 `$main_body->find('div[class=do-not-want]', 0 )->outertext = '';`
 `echo  $main_body->plaintext;`

Comment: `Attempt to assign property of non-object` - Error. I think because the $main_body is an array.

Comment: Did you change the class=do-not-want ?
because it looks like the find function did not find anything inside the $main_body

Comment: of course. i even checked the whole source of the page if the div is really under story page divider.